# PHP/MYSQL- Number operation stops at zero

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

I feel like there is a simple solution, but I cant find it anywhere.

I've got a while() loop and at the beginning of each loop, I subtract 1 from a number that I get from a MYSQL database. But for some reason, it stops at 0. I need the number to go negative if the value pulled from the database is 0 or a negative number.

```
    //Get members
$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members") or die(mysql_error());

//Start the loop
while($members= mysql_fetch_row($select)){

//Get limit
$limit = $members['limit'];
    $newlimit = $limit - 1;

mysql_query("UPDATE `members` SET `limit` = '".$newlim."' WHERE `email`='".$members['email']."'");
}
```

Any advice? This code successfully works until the value gets to 0. But I need it to keep subtraction.

Thanks in advance!
Brandon

Edited: updated the code above. Had an error

Comment: how many times does it need to loop if it's negative? can you add a number to the count if it's negative to make it positive?

Comment: Is your integer column `UNSIGNED` in your table? It must _not_ be in order to store values < 0

Comment: Did you mean to put your update query outside of the while loop?

Comment: Are you doing some sort of check to see if you SHOULD decrease the limit? Because if you really just want to decrease everyone's limit you can do that in one mysql query like so: UPDATE `members` SET `limit` = `limit` - 1;

Comment: @MattBusche The limit decreases according to how many times a user uses a function.

Comment: @ColinMorelli The integer column is not UNSIGNED.

Comment: @cscott It isnt in my code. I just made a mistake when inputing it here. Fixed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that yout `limit` column is an `UNSIGNED INT`. Unsigned numbers can be twice as large as signed numbers, but they cannot have a negative value (hence unsigned).

You could use an ALTER TABLE statement to change the column to `INT`, but you need to be careful because *if any of the values stored in the `limit` field are greater than **2147483647** (if you change it to a signed INT), these values will not be preserved*.

Comment: For some reason my limit column was "VARCHAR" so I went ahead, switched that. I went ahead and used the second example from the post below. And Im still getting 0 as a value. It just won't go negative. Grrr. Anymore insight?

Comment: This is ultimately what gave me the answer because I had already tried using the example below before this question. When I changed the column to INT, it started working. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

remove the extra = symbol

```
$newlimit = $limit - 1;
```

and replace `$newlim` with `$newlimit` in your SQL statement

also please note that you could be doing the same thing in a single SQL statement without any loop or php involved:

```
UPDATE `members` SET `limit`=`limit`-1
```

Comment: The first example isnt giving me a negative value for whatever reason. If the limit value is 0 and I check the database after the code has run, the value remains at zero.

The second example wasn't working for me for some reason so I went to using the code I came up with in my example. I will give this another shot though.

Comment: The code I posted is PHP, so *before* you update your database, `$newlimit` should equal to `-1` if it was zero before. You can then still try to find out why your database isn't updating, if in fact it still isn't (as others have pointed out, you may have to check the data type of your database column)

Comment: The database is definitely updating. Users who have limits greater than 1 are having their limits decreased correctly... until it reaches 0. I will check into your answer again!

Comment: Went back, double checked everything. Got rid of the `$newlim = $lim -1` and just used `UPDATE `members` SET `limit`=`limit`-1` and it worked! Now getting negative numbers! Thank you!